# Ajax ejecuta las validaciones pero no envía el formulario

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Hola que tal? Llevo varios dias tratando de enviar datos desde un formulario a mi correo electrónico. Al menos ya hice que mi función validar se ejecute dentro de la función por donde envio los datos de ajax pero ahora tengo un error con el envío de datos.

Uptedate:

Esta es la función completa que tengo actualmente en mi código fuente.

```
function validarform()
{
  $('.alert').remove();

  var nombre=$('#nombre').val(),
      email=$('#email').val(),
      asunto=$('#asunto').val(),
      mensaje=$('#mensaje').val();

   if(nombre=="" || nombre==null)
  {
      color("nombre");
      Alerta("Campo Nombre es obligatorio");
      return false;

    }
    else
    {
      var error =  /^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]*$/;
      if (!error.test(nombre)) {

        color("nombre");
      Alerta("No se permiten caracteres especiales, ingresar un nombre valido");
      return false;
      }
  }

    if(email=="" || email==null)
    {
      color("email");
      Alerta("Campo Email es obligatorio");
      return false;

    }
    else
    {
      var error =  /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/;
      if (!error.test(email)) {

        color("email");
      Alerta("Por favor ingrese un Email valido");
      return false;
      }
    }

    if(asunto=="" || asunto==null)
    {
      color("asunto");
      Alerta("Campo Asunto es obligatorio");
      return false;

    }
    else
    {
      var error =  /^[,\\.\\a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]*$/;

      if (!error.test(asunto)) {

        color("asunto");
      Alerta("No se permiten caracteres especiales");
      return false;
      }
    }

    if(mensaje=="" || mensaje==null)
    {

      color("mensaje");
      Alerta("Por favor ingrese un mensaje");
      return false;

    }
    else
    {
      var error =  /^[,\\.\\a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]*$/;
      if (!error.test(mensaje)) {

        color("mensaje");
      Alerta("No se permiten caracteres especiales");
      return false;
      }
    }

    return true;

}


$('input').focus(function(){

    $('.alert').remove();
    $('.success').remove();
    colordefecto('nombre');
    colordefecto('email');
    colordefecto('asunto');
});


$('textarea').focus(function(){
    $('.success').remove();
    $('.alert').remove;
    colordefecto('mensaje');
});


function color(color)
{
    $('#' + color).css({

        border: "1px solid #f77474"
    });

    //$('#' + color).val('');
}


function colordefecto(color)
{
  $('#' + color).css({
    border: "1px solid #999"
    });

}


//alerta

function Alerta(alert){

  $('#nombre').before ('<div class="alert"> Alerta: '+ alert +'</div>');

}

//enviamos el formulario

$(function() {
    $('#btn_enviar_contacto').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if( validarform() ){
            var url="Mail.php";
            var nombre=$('#nombre').val();
            var email=$('#email').val();
            var asunto=$('#asunto').val();
            var mensaje=$('#mensaje').val();
            var toPost={nombre:nombre,email:email,asunto:asunto,mensaje:mensaje};

            var request = $.ajax({
                url: url,
                method: "POST",
                data: toPost,
                cache: false, 
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                dataType: "json"
            });

            request.done(function(respuesta) {
                   console.log("respuesta",respuesta);
                   $('.contacto')[0].reset(); 
                   if(respuesta){
                        $('#nombre').before ('<div class="success"> <strong>Gracias '+ respuesta.success +' !!! : </strong> en breve nos contactaremos contigo</div>');
                   }
            });

            request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert(`La petición falló ${textStatus}`);
            });     
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
 <form action="Mail.php" method="POST" class="contacto">
                    <div id="contactform">
                        <div class="col-input">
    <label for="nombre">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" >
    </div>


    <div class="col-input">
    <label for="Email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="correo-e" id="email" >
    </div>

    <div class="col-input">
    <label for="asunto">Asunto</label>
    <input type="text" name="asunto" id="asunto" >
    </div>

    </div>

    <div id="col-text">
  <label for="mensaje">Escribe un comentario</label>
 <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" cols="30" rows="10" ></textarea>
                    </div>

   <button type="button" id="btn_enviar_contacto">Enviar</button>

    </form>
```

Tendre algun error con la URL de archivos? o sera que debo aplicar otra cosa a mi función?

Funcion de validaciones:

```
function validarform()
{
  $('.alert').remove();

  var nombre=$('#nombre').val(),
      email=$('#email').val(),
      asunto=$('#asunto').val(),
      mensaje=$('#mensaje').val();

   if(nombre=="" || nombre==null)
  {
      color("nombre");
      Alerta("Campo Nombre es obligatorio");
      return false;

    }
    else
    {
      var error =  /^[a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]*$/;
      if (!error.test(nombre)) {

        color("nombre");
      Alerta("No se permiten caracteres especiales, ingresar un nombre valido");
      return false;
      }
  }

    if(email=="" || email==null)
    {
      color("email");
      Alerta("Campo Email es obligatorio");
      return false;

    }
    else
    {
      var error =  /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/;
      if (!error.test(email)) {

        color("email");
      Alerta("Por favor ingrese un Email valido");
      return false;
      }
    }

    if(asunto=="" || asunto==null)
    {
      color("asunto");
      Alerta("Campo Asunto es obligatorio");
      return false;

    }
    else
    {
      var error =  /^[,\\.\\a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]*$/;

      if (!error.test(asunto)) {

        color("asunto");
      Alerta("No se permiten caracteres especiales");
      return false;
      }
    }

    if(mensaje=="" || mensaje==null)
    {

      color("mensaje");
      Alerta("Por favor ingrese un mensaje");
      return false;

    }
    else
    {
      var error =  /^[,\\.\\a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]*$/;
      if (!error.test(mensaje)) {

        color("mensaje");
      Alerta("No se permiten caracteres especiales");
      return false;
      }
    }

    return true;

}
```

PHP: Mi codig PHP actual en mi codigo fuente, debido a varias actualizaciones no he conseguido que el mail llegue a mi correo.

```
<?php
    #$_POST es super global, no necesitas pasarle los datos a la funcion
    function ajaxEnviarDatos(){
        #$_POST es superglobal y un array por tanto podemos referirnos a él directamente
        $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $asunto=$_POST['asunto'];
        $mensaje=$_POST['mensaje'];

        $enviar_a = 'guillermo12@gmail.com'; /*Estaba probando otros correos*/
        $asunto = $asunto;
        $mensaje_preparado = "De: $nombre \n";
        $mensaje_preparado .= "Correo: $email \n";
        $mensaje_preparado .= "Mensaje: " . $mensaje;




        #Evaluamos qué ocurre cuando usamos mail
        if ( mail($enviar_a, $asunto, $mensaje_preparado) ) {
            $respuesta=$nombre;
            $respuesta.=$email;
            $respuesta.=$asunto;
            $respuesta.=$mensaje;
            #En vez de un texto plano, creamos un array
            #tendrá la clave success si mail es exitoso
            $mData=array("success"=>$respuesta);
        }else{
            #O tendrá la clave error si hay un error
            $mData=array("error"=>"mail no ha funciona, revisa tu configuración");          
        }
        return $mData;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['nombre'])){
        $mData=ajaxEnviarDatos();
    }else{
        $mData=array("error"=>"Falta el nombre", "datos"=>$_POST);          
    }
    echo json_encode($mData);

?>
```

[image: Localizacion de archivos]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Haz depurado algo? ¿Qué imprime `console.log(validarform());`? Pon un `console.log` también en la parte del `success`. Debes activar la consola de Javascript para ver las salidas de consola.

Comment: Amigo probe lo que me dices y me esta ejecutando las validaciones correctamente.  Cuando completo todo me dice. console.log(validarform());
undefined
true

Comment: Creo que en la pestaña red me deberia salir la ejecución Mail.php pero lo hace.

Comment: Hay que ver de dónde sale ese `undefined`, eso no es buena señal. ¿Depuraste en el  `success`?

Comment: Dentro de la consola coloque: console.log(validarForm()); , si no completo el formulario sale. undefined
false ahora si completo todo sale undefined
true. Ahora coloco console.log(success(respuesta)); y me sale ReferenceError: success is not defined

Comment: edite el mensaje para que puedes ver el code de la funcion

Comment: Está mal escrito así: `console.log(success(respuesta));`, con esto, que ya lo tienes: `console.log("respuesta",respuesta);` deberías ver en la consola si está entrando o no al success.

Comment: Estas ejecutando dos veces la función `validarform()` una antes del `if` y otra en la condición. Lo mas sencillo es que pongas `console.log("Entra en el if")` dentro del `if` para saber si entra, y lo mismo en el `success/error`

Comment: Gracias por contestar, acabo de quitar la invocación del método que estaba en el if de arriba, cuando veo en consola la parte del if veo que si me esta haciendo caso las alertas, pero cuando veo el success me sale undefined
respuesta

Comment: No me quiere hacer el post :s

Comment: Actualizo: tenia un error en el codigo con el post Data, y estaba espeficando las referencias con el mismo nombre. Lo corregi pero aun asi no me envia recibe el Mail.php :(

Answer (score 1):

Intenta de este modo.

He corregido un poco el código, quitando elementos innecesarios o repetitivos y aplicando prácticas recomendadas como el uso de `function` en vez de `document ready`, el uso de `done` en vez de `success`, incorporando además un control de fallos de la petición Ajax mediante `fail`.

**Atención a esto:** En la petición Ajax indicaste un `dataType: "json"`. Entonces desde el PHP deberías devolver un JSON. Si devuelves contenido plano entonces cámbialo por `html`.

Prueba de este modo y me dices si hay algún problema.

## Javascript (cliente)

```
$(function() {
    $('#btn_enviar_contacto').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if( validarform() ){
            var url="Mail.php";
            var nombre=$('#nombre').val();
            var email=$('#email').val();
            var asunto=$('#asunto').val();
            var mensaje=$('#mensaje').val();
            var toPost: {nombre:nombre,email:email,asunto:asunto,mensaje:mensaje};
    
            var request = $.ajax({
                url: url,
                method: "POST",
                data: toPost,
                cache: false, 
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                dataType: "json"
            });
    
            request.done(function(respuesta) {
                   console.log("respuesta",respuesta);
                   $('.contacto')[0].reset(); 
                   if(respuesta.success){
                        $('#nombre').before ('<div class="success"> <strong>Gracias '+ respuesta.success +' !!! : </strong> en breve nos contactaremos contigo</div>');
                   } else {
                       console.log(respuesta.error); //Esto se puede mostrar en un div si quieres
                   }
            });
    
            request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert(`La petición falló ${textStatus}`);
            });        
        }
    });
});
```

---

## PHP (servidor)

Tienes un error fundamental en tu código PHP: te estás refiriendo mal a los valores que debería haber en `$_POST`. Como lo tienes no encontraría jamás los datos porque las claves de array en PHP son case sensitive. Si observas en el código Javascript, el objeto que estás enviando a PHP es este:

```
var toPost: {nombre:nombre,email:email,asunto:asunto,mensaje:mensaje};
```

¿Qué significa eso, que **los nombres de clave** serán los que hay a la izquierda de cada par, o sea, `nombre, email, asunto, mensaje` ... pero si en el `$_POST` usas `Nombre, Email...`empezando con mayúscula, no los encontrará nunca.

Otro error (de redundancia) es que `$_POST` en sí es un array, por lo tanto, no tiene sentido sacar los datos de `$_POST` que es ya un array, para meterlos en otro array.

Otro error es que no estabas respondiendo un JSON en sí. Para un JSON tienes que crear un array. Aquí he creado un array con una propiedad  `success` cuando el email se mande, o `error` cuando no se mande, evaluando a su vez con `if` la llamada a `mail()`

```
<?php
    #$_POST es super global, no necesitas pasarle los datos a la funcion
    function ajaxEnviarDatos(){
        #$_POST es superglobal y un array por tanto podemos referirnos a él directamente
        $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $asunto=$_POST['asunto'];
        $mensaje=$_POST['mensaje'];

        $enviar_a = 'guillermo@gmail.com';
        $asunto = $asunto;
        $mensaje_preparado = "De: $nombre \n";
        $mensaje_preparado .= "Correo: $email \n";
        $mensaje_preparado .= "Mensaje: " . $mensaje;
        #Evaluamos qué ocurre cuando usamos mail
        if ( mail($enviar_a, $asunto, $mensaje_preparado) ) {
            $respuesta=$nombre;
            $respuesta.=$email;
            $respuesta.=$asunto;
            $respuesta.=$mensaje;
            #En vez de un texto plano, creamos un array
            #tendrá la clave success si mail es exitoso
            $mData=array("success"=>$respuesta);
        }else{
            #O tendrá la clave error si hay un error
            $mData=array("error"=>"mail no ha funciona, revisa tu configuración");            
        }
        return $mData;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['nombre'])){
        $mData=ajaxEnviarDatos();
    }else{
        $mData=array("error"=>"Falta el nombre");            
    }
    echo json_encode($mData);

?>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104075/discussion-on-answer-by-a-cedano-ajax-ejecuta-las-validaciones-pero-no-envia-el).

Comment: No se si es que estoy informado mal, pero debo hacer otro código y colocar algo diferente en la URL dentro del ajax? Tanto función ajax que me pasaste y la función de validaciones, todas están en un mismo archivo envioajax.js

Comment: Osea me refiero a que si la función de validaciones debe estar en otro archivo .js y luego llamarlo desde envioajax.js (en envioajax.js tengo la funcion del ajax y mas arriba tengo la otro funcion de validacion) las 2 funciones estan en un mismo archivo.

Comment: Pase el consol y me sale: Object { nombre: "Raul", email: "Raultorres@gmail.com", asunto: "Hola", mensaje: "Necesito ayuda con mi codigo" }

Comment: @EndersonPerez eso no tiene nada que ver, lo importante es que la URL del archivo al que diriges la petición Ajax sea la correcta. Intenta quitar estas tres opciones que hay en la petición Ajax: `cache: false, contentType: false, processData: false,` a ver qué ocurre. También limpia el caché del navegador.

Comment: Imagenita.. borrando, quitando, probando código nuevo en el php y ni siquiera se me ocurrió quitar esas propiedades.. Gracias nuevamente, ahora si me llegan los correos.

Comment: @EndersonPerez me alegro de que al fin funcione. Si la respuesta te ha servido considera marcarla como aceptada para que la pregunta no aparezca como sin resolver. Saludos.

Comment: Aunque estuve probando a ver si podía aceptarme alguna de ellas y puedo notar que contentType y processData son las que me generan errores. Investigando un poco, vi en los foros ingleses de stackoverflow que esa propiedades puede usarse pero debes instanciarse y luego recorrerse con un ciclo (aunque no es tan igual pero es más o menos la idea).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery

Comment: En parte puede darte un voto bien grande?

Comment: @EndersonPerez eso seria tema para otra pregunta. Allí se habla de `FormData` que sirve para cosas más complejas, por ejemplo cuando quieres enviar archivos adjuntos usando el formulario. Eso no aplica aquí, porque sólo quieres enviar datos planos como el nombre, el email, etc. De hecho, en tu código original había un `FormData` que quité como código innecesario y redundante porque la intención no era enviar adjuntos.